# Evaluation of an infinite double sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

First of all, my apologies for this trivial question. But I keep getting the wrong answer. I hope someone can point out my error.

Let $\lvert \theta \rvert > 1$. The double sum that I have is as follows. Let $h \in \mathbb{Z}$. The claim is that $S(h) = 0$ whenever $h \neq 0$.

$$S(h) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (-\theta)^{-j}(-\theta)^{-i}f(i,j,h)$$
where
$$f(i,j,h) = \begin{cases}\sigma^2(1+\theta^2) & h - i + j = 0\\ \theta\sigma^2& \lvert h -i +j\rvert = 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I first rewrite the sum as follows.
$$S(h) = \sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} (-\theta)^{-j}(-\theta)^{-i}f(i,j,h)1_{i\geq 0}1_{j\geq 0}$$
Then I define $k = i-h$. For a fixed $h$, if $i$ runs from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, then so does $k$. So then I can write 
$$S(h) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} (-\theta)^{-j}(-\theta)^{-k-h}f(k,j,h)1_{k+h\geq 0}1_{j\geq 0}$$
$$f(k,j,h) = \begin{cases}\sigma^2(1+\theta^2) &  j - k = 0\\ \theta\sigma^2& \lvert j-k\rvert = 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Rewriting the sum again
$$S(h) = (-\theta)^{-h}\sum_{k=-h}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (-\theta)^{-j}(-\theta)^{-k}f(k,j,h)$$
I get a nonzero $S(h)$ for $h \neq 0$ as opposed to the claim in the exercise I am trying to solve. So this is where I am stuck.